# Map behavior changes when changed to landscape orientation using fragments

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs, android-fragments

I was able to load Google Map in a tab layout using fragments and viewpager. It works on both portrait and landscape orientation. When I first load the app, as I switch to the map tab, the map loads, camera animates on my marker which has pre defined lat and long and my current location is enabled. However, if I change tabs, then go back to the maps tab,  the location finder button is gone (upper left button) the camera does not animate to the marker I set because the marker is gone, the map displays africa.

Here is my code for the maps tab.

**TabTwo.java**

```
public class TabTwo extends Fragment {

private static View view;
/**
 * Note that this may be null if the Google Play services APK is not
 * available.
 */

private static GoogleMap map;
private static Double latitude, longitude;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_two, container, false);
    // Passing harcoded values for latitude & longitude. Please change as per your need. This is just used to drop a Marker on the Map
            latitude = 14.6353475;
            longitude = 121.0327501;

            setUpMapIfNeeded(); // For setting up the MapFragment

    return view;
}

/***** Sets up the map if it is possible to do so *****/
public static void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (map == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) MainActivity.fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (map != null)
            setUpMap();
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the
 * camera.
 * <p>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap}
 * is not null.
 */
private static void setUpMap() {
    // For showing a move to my loction button
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Estuar Building").snippet("Work Place"));
    // For zooming automatically to the Dropped PIN Location
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,
            longitude), 12.0f));
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (map != null)
        setUpMap();

    if (map == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) MainActivity.fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (map != null)
            setUpMap();
    }
}

/**** The mapfragment's id must be removed from the FragmentManager
 **** or else if the same it is passed on the next time then 
 **** app will crash ****/
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    try {
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

}
```

Need help. Thanks!

Comment: I also found out that I lock my device, the location finder button disappears.

Comment: How do you get your current location? I don't see the proper code in yours. That's why you see the ocean. Also, when you click on the tab for the second time, are you sure your methods are called? Did you put a breakpoint?

Comment: I use this function so I can check if the Google Map knows my location " map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);"

Comment: "Also, when you click on the tab for the second time, are you sure your methods are called? Did you put a breakpoint?"

I'm not sure how to answer that sentence. I'm sorry.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in each of your fragment methods, so you can see, the second time you press on the map tab, which method is executed. IT seems to me something is missing the second time you enter in that tab, probably because the fragment is already allocated.

Comment: The logcat says GooglePlay is missing because I can't run the google map on the emulator.

Comment: The goal of breakpoints is to check if everything you need for your map is executed the second time also. Do you have a real device? Use that and run the app in debug mode.

Comment: ok. will get back to you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map displays Africa = Map displays GPS (0,0). Everywhere, always. :)

Your `setUpMapsIfNeeded` is buggy. The map object you have on your UI is not the map that you have in the map variable. You **must** always re-fill all UI variables in `onCreateView`

Android recreates your view when the fragment was not shown. The map object on the view (and visible to the user) is not the one you have in your variable.

If you don't call

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment)MainActivity.fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

everytime you create a new view in `onCreateView` you won't have the correct map and all your setup code will not work.

Comment: but I only have one fragment for the map. How is map on my UI different in the map that i have in the map variable?

Comment: Because the fragment was not shown for a few seconds. Android will destroy your UI when you switch tabs.

Comment: so in the `onDestroy`, I have to call `setUpMapIfNeeded` again?

Comment: I tried to call `setUpMapIfNeeded`, doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: no. Just scrap the whole if checks and put the rest into `onCreateView` your problem is the `if (map == null) {` part

Comment: so I'll remove `setUpMapIfNeeded` and put it on `onCreate`?

Comment: Android recreates your view. The map object on the view (and visible to the user) is not the one you have in your variable. If you don't call `map = ((SupportMapFragment) MainActivity.fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();` everytime you create a new view in `onCreateView` you won't have the correct map and all your setup code will not work.

Comment: so I have to call it everytime? sorry i'm new to fragments and all this recreating stuff.

Comment: Fragments disappearing from screen is like Activities going into background. Yes you have to call this everytime.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39328/discussion-between-meredrica-and-miguel-rivera)